# Can I use Amelia package in R to impute missing values in a univariate time series data?

Tags: r

Amelia package in R is commonly used for multivariate time series data but can I apply it for a univariate variable?

Comment: According to [this article (PDF)](https://arxiv.org/ftp/arxiv/papers/1510/1510.03924.pdf) the answer is "No".

Comment: Thank you so much neilfws for assisting me. Can you suggest any other imputation methods that can be used to impute missing values for univariate time series data?